# Apache2 dynamic custom filename for log files

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I would like to apply a date based custom filename for apache2 log files, which I want to use for [clickheat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html).
In the [example](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/156894.html) it writes:

```
CustomLog "clickheat.%Y-%m-%d-%H" "%r" env=clickheat
```

But for me it creates a file with name `clickheat.%Y-%m-%d-%H` the variables are not substituted.

I have not found in apache2 docs which parameter should I enable or set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send logs to command ("|/usr/bin/rotatelogs <path_with_format> <time|size>"). Like this one:

```
# Check path to rotatelogs and log file directory
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/apache/clickheat.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600" "%r" env=clickheat
```

Comment: Looks like this is strftime-substitution only. It'd be nice to substitute hostnames or some other variables.